# Tsql substring / charindex

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, charindex

I have the following text field and am trying to pull the name following "Reviewed By".  How can i do this in TSQL?
His information looks like:

```
<p>Assessed By: Joe Thomas</p>
<p>Reviewed By: Fred Smith</p>
<p>The end of document</p>
```

Comment: So, you even know the names of the necessary functions. What else do you need?

Comment: Downvote as, per the downvote mouseover, "this question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it more flexible for different string that you can pass with a variable, you can do something like this.

```
  DECLARE @Mytext AS VARCHAR(200) 
SET @Mytext = '<p>Assessed By: Joe Thomas</p>
<p>Reviewed By: Fred Smith</p>
<p>The end of document</p>'

SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@Mytext, 42), CHARINDEX('<', RIGHT(@Mytext, 42)) - 1)
```

/* Or to make it more robust you can compute the index value 
       instead of passing a fixed value, 42 in this case.
       12 is the length of the text 'Reviewed By: */

```
    SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@Mytext, (LEN(@Mytext) - 
    PATINDEX('%Reviewed By:%', @Mytext)) - 12), 
    CHARINDEX('<', RIGHT(@Mytext,LEN(@Mytext) - 
    PATINDEX ('%Reviewed By:%', @Mytext) - 12)) - 1)
```